# Is it good UX practice to expand the tab on demand?

Tags: interaction-design, tabs

For example,
There are 3 tabs.
Once I select any one of the tabs, is it okay to expand the width of the tab and show the options in selected tab along with other unopenedtabs.

http://framebox.org/wRre

Comment: I'd say that it's OK, it makes it look like a rather modern, or sleek design.

Comment: Can you share more about the context this UI is going to be used in? It's hard to judge it as good or bad otherwise

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't advise doing that. User usually perceive an expanded list of options to be a drop down menu. Sideways menu might throw them off. Implementation could be challenging too especially if your app needs to be responsive. You probably have to be extra careful when you placed additional components beside the 3 buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Potential issues with this approach:

- The sub-options' positioning is too similar to the tabs themselves -- unless you're *very* clear with the visual cues there's potential for users to not realize the hierarchy here, and think the sub-options are themselves new tabs rather than being contained inside the selected tab.
- You're inevitably going to run out of room for options, and have to deal with wrapping to new lines.  Horizontal space is limited, vertical space is effectively infinite.
- It changes the location of the other tabs (if any but the last tab is expanded), inviting misclicks.
- It's a new, unfamiliar design metaphor, with no clear purpose. There are already plenty of design metaphors for hierarchical structures which will be more immediately familiar to most users: trees, accordions containing tabs or vice versa, tabs-within-tabs, tabs-with-vertical-submenus, etc.  All have their advantages and disadvantages -- without more detail about your design it's not possible to say which would best suit your needs -- but in general unless there's a compelling reason to invent something new that users may need time to get used to, it's probably better to stick with something more familiar.

Answer (score -1):

This is one of the best example for snappy UI.

But, there is risk involved with this approach. In general user tend not to wait for more than half a second for navigation. With this mental model, expanding a tab and activating contextual buttons/actions should be handled carefully.

This could be effectively achieved by distinct visual design, transition/animation, increasing app performance, and reducing freedom of the user and having control on the system.

Comment: "This is one of the best example for snappy UI."  Could you back up this statement?  An example of a design that does this with "snappy" results, as well as some supporting reasons why this is a good design, would strengthen your answer.